# Subquery issue when trying to find number of things happening in a given month occur more than the previous month

Tags: mysql

My query is as follows:

```
select challenges_unique_acronym from presents where
 (select count(month(MonthA.present_date)) from presents as MonthA group by month(MonthA.present_date)) 
 > 
 (select count(month(MonthA.present_date) - 1) from presents as MonthA group by month(MonthA.present_date));
```

`(count(month(MonthA.present_date))) from presents as MonthA group by month(MonthA.present_date);` returns the number of times a month appears where each distinct month is on a seperate row
[like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6k49.png), 
but since they're in multiple rows Im getting the "subquery returns more than 1 row" thing which prevents me from equating them.

Is there a way that i can tell mysql "For each row check whether:

(select count(month(MonthA.present_date)) from presents as MonthA group by month(MonthA.present_date))

is greater than

(select count(month(MonthA.present_date) - 1) from presents as MonthA group by month(MonthA.present_date));"

Comment: These two expressions are equivalent: `count(month(MonthA.present_date))` and `count(month(MonthA.present_date) - 1)`. The `>` condition will never be satisfied.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. Your question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a hìjoin with teh subquery

```
    select presents.challenges_unique_acronym 
    from presents 
    INNER JOIN  (
        select month(MonthA.present_date) month, count(month(MonthA.present_date)) count
        from presents as MonthA 
        group by month(MonthA.present_date)
        ) t1 ON t1.month = month(presents.present_date)
    INNER JOIN  (
        select month(MonthA.present_date) month, count(month(MonthA.present_date) - 1) count
       from presents as MonthA 
       group by month(MonthA.present_date) 

    ) t2 ON t1.month = t2.month 
        AND t1.count > t2.count; -- adding this comment to make the eddit 6 characters
```

Comment: I get an error saying every derived table needs to have an alias

Comment: Thank you.
So This basically put them into their own columns and checked which count was greater than the the other. How did this get pass the "subquery returning more than 1 row error?

Comment: The ".." made your explanation a bit confusing, lol. So this idea of this method to use inner joins to get past the error is to:
Return more than 1 row, but join the columns so the compiler knows its ok for that to happen?

Comment: Yes   sorry for   .....  anyway when you use a comparison operator, as = , > or you select column  you tell to the db engine that you aspecting just un value. When you uise JOIN you tell to the db engine that you want compare two sets of values using the ON clause content as intersection for the Sets. Hope this explanation is more clear.